# Merge code between two dfferent git repositories

Tags: git, merge, repository, git-merge

I have readonly access to `repo A` and have my own `repo B`.
`Repo A` contained multiple branches `A1`, `A2` etc `repo B` has branches `B1`, `B2` etc. Both `repo A` and `repo B` has remotes

`Repo A` `branch A1` equal to `repo B` `branch B1` `folder F` so how can I merge all changes from `repo A` `branch A1` to `repo B` `branch B1` `folder F` using git command by keeping all the history?

Currently I am just copying the files manually by overriding the content on `B1` `folder F` which is not right I believe.

**UPDATE what I've done so far:**

1) on `branch B` directory i run a command `git remote add A path/to/A`

2) then `git fetch A` so I've got all stuff from `repo A` in my `repo B`

So the question now how can I merge `branch A1` to `branch B` `folder F`
there is a command `git merge A/A1` but how can I specify that I want to merge `branch A1` to `branch B1` `folder F` in that command ?

Comment: How did you create "repoB"? Was it originally cloned from "repoA"?

Comment: @Thilo I just copy files manually. And both `repo A` and `repo B` has remotes