# How to restore my added but not committed files that was modified by git

Tags: git, github

I did a stupid thing; I did 'git fetch' on local repository that was not committed. So my files now overwritten by it. How I can restore my plight that was before this stupid mistake?

[image: git_status_1]

[image: git_status_2]

things that I've done:

1. Modify some file on web-github-commit this (because I'm stupid)
2. git add .
3. git commit -m
4. git push origin branchA -> that was rejected because of the commit I've done from website
5. git reset --hard HEAD^ (because I'm really stupid)
6. git push origin branchA -> rejected because remote contains the work that I do not have locally (same reason as 4)
7. git fetch -> counting objects 5
8. git reset --hard HEAD^ (this is the point when I was starting to think that I'm doing shit)
9. git reset 'HEAD@{1}' -> my files modified (I'm sorry initially I was thinking that git fetch botched my life)

Comment: I was under the impression that `git fetch` would not affect the working tree... could you describe your situation in more detail? What does `git status` show?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591887/how-to-undo-git-fetch

Comment: @DaisyShipton, images attached, thanks for prompt reaction!

Comment: Okay, so it shows those modifications - are those not just the changes you've made? It's still not really clear that the problem is.

Comment: `git fetch` does not affect the work tree. You did something else.

Comment: @DaisyShipton, full list of stupid things now listed! I'm already sorry for misleading title

Comment: So hang on, you *have* committed the changes? Are you just trying to get back to that commit? I suspect that `git reflog` is your friend at this point, so that you can check back to the commit you want, then merge in other changes.

Comment: @DaisySHipton, yes, i have my local commit in 'git reflog', on HEAD@{3} - should i just use another git reset?

Comment: @user9403409: That would probably be my first port of call, yes.

Comment: @DaisySHipton, you are my savior! Could you please make an answer so i could check you as right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just performing a `git fetch` doesn't touch the working tree. (`git pull` would try, because that does a `fetch` followed by a `merge`, but that's a different matter.)

It looks like you *have* committed the changes though - but then confused yourself afterwards (which can be easy to do with git, certainly...)

Fortunately, `git reflog` is your friend: it will show you everything you've done, including the commit hashes along the way. Run it and find the commit you want to get back to, then use `git reset --hard <commit>` to get back there. You can then merge the fetched changes, or rebase, or whatever it is you want to do.