# Not sure if I lost my local changes, how to get it back and push to a specified remote branch

Tags: git, github

I have a feeling that I overwritten my local changes with what's in remote...how can I recover it?

I have a remote branch `develop`. I also have a local branch which wasn't a git repo.

I made my local directory a git repo by doing `git init`. I want to add everything I have locally to the remote develop branch so I tried:

```
git remote add origin git@github.....
git fetch
git add .
git commit -m "some comment"
git status
```

but it tells me:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

which I found weird.. so I tried

```
git push origin develop
```

But I got the error:

```
error: src refspec develop does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:.....'
```

So I thought I needed to be on develop so I did:

```
git checkout develop
git push
```

But then it tells me everything is up to date

But when I go to github's develop branch I don't see the changes I've committed.

I tried to undo the `git fetch` from what is shown here: [How to undo 'git fetch'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591887/how-to-undo-git-fetch)

so I did `git remote remove origin` but that did nothing.

What did I do wrong and how can I get my original changes back so I can push it to develop in remote?

UPDATE:

From `git reflog` I see:

```
a1be24c (HEAD -> develop) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to develop
771b082 (master) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from develop to master
a1be24c (HEAD -> develop) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to develop
771b082 (master) HEAD@{3}: commit (initial): trying to keep develop up to date ..
```

I see `771b082 (master) HEAD@{3}: commit (initial): trying to keep develop up to date ..` is my first commit. I think that is what I need to get back my local source code.

Comment: Start with `git reflog` before going crazy. Keep in mind, tou may not see a commit in `git log` meanwhile it'll be in `git reflog`.

Answer (score 7):

## git reflog

`git reflog` shows you a list of every commit you've visited recently. Even if you deleted the local branch, you can still go to the latest commit and then create a branch at that location.

So, do that first.

Once that's done, you can figure out whether you need to do any branch surgery to integrate your work with the rest of the repo.

Comment: so I did ```git reflog``` and I can see my initial commit is there. But how do I get it back?

Comment: Is it just git reset --hard 771b082? But isn't that the same as ``` checkout: moving from develop to master```?

Comment: Checkout the commit. Then create a branch at that commit with `git checkout -b my-abandoned-work`. At this point, you have rescued your almost-lost work, and can consider your options for integrating the work with the rest of the repo.

Answer (score 6):

## TL;DR

You don't have to search.  Your `master` branch contains your one commit.  But you *do *have to do something about the way you made it, which isn't useful.

Exactly what you want to do will depend on a lot of things, and really needs a much longer discussion.  My guess is that you will want to start with `git worktree add`.  See the "how to recover" section below (but not until you understand the long part).

## Long

> ```
> 771b082 (master) HEAD@{3}: commit (initial): trying to keep develop up to date ..
> ```

The `commit (initial)` is the real clue here.  What this means is that you created a local repository (`git init`), which put you on *your own* branch named `master`.  This branch *did not exist yet*.  This is a confusing state of affairs; see below.

You then ran:

> ```
> git remote add origin git@github.....
> git fetch
> ```

This added a *remote:* a short name, in this case `origin`, for a way for your Git software to reach out to another separate Git repository.  The `git fetch` then *did* reach out to this other Git repository (successfully, apparently) and got from it, all of its commits, and *none of its branches*.  When `git fetch` runs, your Git software gets to see *all of their branch names*, but instead of just copying their branch names to create or update your own branches—which would be bad: see more below—your Git software then *renames* each of their branch names.  Their `develop`, for instance, becomes your `origin/develop`.  This name with `origin/` in front of it—the `origin` part comes from the name `origin` in `git remote add origin ...`—is a *remote-tracking name*, which your Git software uses to remember, in your repository, *their* repository's *branch* names.

So you now have all of their commits, and none of their branches: instead, for each of their *branch* names, you have a *remote-tracking name*.  That's all `git fetch` does (get any of their commits that are new to you, and update your remote-tracking names) so `git fetch` is now finished.

Then you ran:

> ```
> git add .
> git commit -m "trying to keep develop up to date"
> ```

Since you're (still) on your branch `master`, which still doesn't exist, this added all your working-tree files—none of which are from any of their commits—and made one new commit in your repository, *creating* your branch named `master`.

Your:

> ```
> git status
> ```

then showed you on your branch master, with nothing to commit, because you've just committed everything.  So your working tree (and Git's index) match your one commit that you just made.

You then attempted `git push origin develop`, but as you had no *branch* named `develop` at this point, that failed.  (You did have `origin/develop`, but that's a *remote-tracking name* and spelled `origin/develop`, not `develop`).  Then you ran:

> ```
> git checkout develop
> ```

Since you had no branch named `develop` at this point, you might expect an error, but both `git checkout` and `git switch` have a special feature here.  If you don't tell Git *not* to do this with `--no-guess`, Git will now *guess what you meant to do*.  Git's guess will search for a remote-tracking name that ends in `develop`.  You have one!  It's `origin/develop`.  So the search succeeds and finds exactly one.  Git's guessing code then *guesses* that you *meant* to run:

```
git checkout -b develop --track origin/develop
```

So your Git now *creates* a new branch name, `develop`, pointing to the *same commit* as your `origin/develop`.  You now have a branch named `develop` that you can switch to, and `git checkout` now does that.

Your `develop` is now even with your `origin/develop`, of course.  It's entirely separate from your own `master`, and contains no commits from your `master`.  If, at this point, you were to run:

```
git log --all --decorate --graph
```

(without `--oneline` as it's deceptive in this case) you would see two disjoint graphs, one for `develop` / `origin/develop` (both names select the same commit), and one for `master` containing one commit.

#### What's going on here, and why this is so confusing

Git is, really, all about *commits*.  Git is not about *files*, although commits *hold* files, and Git is not about *branches* either, although branch names help you (and Git) *find* commits.  It's really all about the commits.

Every commit in a repository is numbered, with a universally unique hash ID.  If two Git repositories have two commits that have the *same* number, they must necessarily have the *same commit*.  So if your Git repository has a commit with number `a1be24c` (abbreviated: it's actually 40 hexadecimal digits long), and *their* Git repository has a commit with the same number, you and they have the same commit.  You got it from them, or they got it from you, or both of you got it from a third Git repository perhaps, but one way or another, you both have the *same commit*.

This means your Git repository and their Git repository can just compare these hash IDs to see who has what.  Any commits they have, that you don't, you'll get with `git fetch`.  Any commits you have that they don't, you *can* give them with `git push` (though you won't necessarily give them *everything* you have that they don't, as `git push` is more complicated than `git fetch` here, the way we'll use it).

Aside from this rather magical numbering trick,<sup>1</sup> each commit *contains* two things:

- Any given commit contains a full snapshot of every file Git knew about at the time you, or whoever, made the commit.  For instance, your one commit on your `master` knew about files from `git add .`, so those are the files in that commit.  These files are in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and *de-duplicated* format, so if you keep recommitting the same version of some file—which is very normal—there's really only one *actual* copy in the repository.  But each such commit "holds" the (shared) copy.  (This is safe because *all parts* of *every* commit are read-only, which is necessary for the magical numbering trick.)
- Any given commit also contains some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the author of the commit.  It includes some date-and-time stamps.  It includes any log message you gave (`git commit -m ...`).  And—crucially for Git's own operation—each commit stores, in this metadata, a list of *previous* commit hash IDs.  This list is usually exactly one element long, but for an "initial" or "root" commit it's *empty*.

If we look at how this works in a less-confusing situation than an initial, totally-empty repository, we see something like this.  Let's draw commits using single uppercase letters such as `H` to stand in for hash IDs:

```
            <-H
```

Here, `H` is the *last* commit in our repository, on the main or master branch for instance (we'll assume just one branch name at this point rather than the two or three we more often see).  Being a commit, `H` holds both a snapshot and metadata.  The metadata tells us who made `H`, but importantly, it holds the *hash ID* of the *previous* commit, which we draw as a backwards-pointing arrow.  This pretend-arrow "points to" the previous or *parent* commit, which has some random-looking hash ID, but we'll call it `G`:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Of course, `G` is a commit, so it has a snapshot and metadata, and the metadata include a single backwards-pointing arrow (a single hash ID) that lets Git find still-earlier commit `F`, which is `G`'s parent:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

This just keeps going and going, except that eventually it *has to stop*, because some commit (commit `A`) was the *very first* commit.  Commit `A` has *no* parent, because there's no previous commit:

```
A <-B <-C ... <-H
```

The way Git really works is that it starts from the end, at commit `H`, and works *backwards*.  When it reaches the beginning—a *root commit* with no parent—it finally gets to stop.

For Git to *find* commit `H`, something—perhaps you, the human—has to provide *to* Git the raw hash ID *of* commit `H`.  Memorizing hash IDs is a ridiculous task, of course, but it's also completely unnecessary.  We have a computer: we can just have the *computer* memorize the last hash ID.  This is where *branch names* come in.

---

<sup>1</sup>How does your Git software know, at the time you run `git commit`, that the hash ID it assigns to your *new* commit is different from every other existing hash ID everywhere?  The answer is that it doesn't: it relies on probability.  And yet, this actually works in practice.

---

#### Branch names point to last commits

Just as commits point backwards to their parent commits, by holding the parent commit's hash ID, a branch name points to a *last* commit by holding the hash ID.  So we can extend our drawing a bit:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

Now instead of having to memorize some hash ID, we can just give Git the name `master`.  That's a *branch name* and by definition, whatever hash ID is inside the name *is* the last commit "on" that branch.

Let's suppose now that we decide to create one new branch name `br1`, with `git branch br1` or `git checkout -b br1` or `git switch -c br1`.  The last two do the same thing, while the first one—`git branch br1`—creates the name *without* switching *to* it.  Either way, the new name *also points to commit `H`* right now, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, master
```

We now need a way to tell which *name* we're using to *find commit `H`*.  The way Git does this is to attach the special name `HEAD` to one of the two branch names:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, master (HEAD)
```

This means we're "on" master; if we now run `git checkout br1` we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), master
```

which means we're "on" `br1`.  Either way we're *using* commit `H`, so for the moment it wouldn't matter which branch we're on.  But now let's create a new commit (e.g., by changing a file, using `git add`, and running `git commit`—this will create a new snapshot, reusing the unchanged files, and adding a new version of the one changed file).<sup>2</sup>

Anyway, to make the new commit, Git saves out the snapshot, adds the metadata—including hash ID `H`, which is that of the *current* commit—and writes all of this out as the new commit, which assigns the new commit its new, unique hash ID; we'll just call it "commit `I`":

```
          I
         /
...--G--H
```

Since `I` is now the *latest* commit "on" whichever branch we're on, Git *updates that branch name*—the one to which `HEAD` is attached—to point to new commit `I`.  The other branch names remain unchanged, so if `HEAD` is attached to `br1`, we now have:

```
          I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
```

Note that commits up through `H` are on *both branches*, not just `master`.  Commit `I` is only on `br1` at this point, though that could change in the future.

If we now `git checkout master`, Git will:

- rip out all the files that go with commit `I` (they're safely saved, read-only, *in* commit `I` so this is safe to do);
- replace them with all the files that go with commit `H` (extracted *from* commit `H`)

and now we have:

```
          I   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

If you look at the files in your *working tree*, you'll see the files from `H`, rather than those from `I`.  Of course many of them will be exactly the same (you only changed one file), and Git also secretly works hard behind the scenes not to bother to rip out then re-create a file that *isn't* going to change and that makes the claim that it rips-and-replaces *all* the files a little too strong, but thinking about it this way works pretty well, to get you started.

If you switch back to `br1` you get the commit-`I` files again:

```
          I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
```

and if you now make another commit you get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
```

New commit `J` is the last, and `br1` points to `J`; `J` points backwards to `I`, which points backwards to `H`, and so on.

If you switch back to `master` and create `br2` and switch to `br2`, you get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2 (HEAD), master
```

and if you now create two *more* new commits you get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

This is how branches work, in Git.

---

<sup>2</sup>Note that `git add` winds up:

- compressing the file;
- checking for duplicates;
- if a duplicate, discarding the newly compressed file and using the original;
- if not a duplicate, arranging for the newly compressed file to be truly added, and using that.

So it doesn't hurt to `git add` an *unchanged* file.  It does take a bunch of extra CPU work though, so Git will try to guess at cases where it can *pretend* to have `git add`-ed a file without actually bothering.  In a few very rare cases you may find that you must override this pretending, with, e.g., `git add --renormalize`.

---

#### Remote-tracking names find commits just like branch names

Let's suppose we have a repository with this in it:

```
          I--J   <-- dev (HEAD), origin/dev
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

You might get this by cloning a repository that has both `master` and `dev` on it (creating your `origin/master` and your `origin/dev`) and then doing a `git checkout dev`, which creates your `dev` pointing to the same commit as their `dev`, i.e., as your `origin/dev`.

Now we wait a day (or an hour, or a second, or some time interval), long enough for them to add two commits to *their* `dev`.  Then we run `git fetch`.  Our Git reaches out to their Git software and their repository and finds two now commits `K-L` that they have that we don't, so our `git fetch` *gets* those commits.  Meanwhile *their* `dev` now points to (shared) commit `L`.  So our Git software now updates *our* `origin/dev` to remember where their `dev` points *now:*

```
               K--L   <-- origin/dev
              /
          I--J   <-- dev (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

Our `dev` has fallen behind, not because of something we did—we did nothing at all—but because *they* have *added* commits to *their* `dev`.  We might now want to force our own `dev` to move forward to `L`, to match their `dev`.  (To keep this answer from getting ridiculously long, I'll skip over *how* to do that.  Just note that it looks like there are separate `dev` branches, `dev` and `origin/dev`.  And there sort of are: it all depends on what we mean by *branch*.  Is a branch "a commit pointed to by a name", or is it a branch *name* in *our repository*, or is it some collection of commits, or what?  See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  Humans use the word ambiguously, so you have to ask what someone—sometimes even yourself—means when you hear "branch".)

#### The weirdness of a new, totally empty repository

In Git, a *branch name* **must** point to exactly one commit.  But in a new, empty branch, we have *no commits* (count them: zero, zilch, nada, none).  So we can't have any *branch names* either.

Nonetheless, Git can attach `HEAD` to a non-existent branch name, something like this:

```
master (HEAD)
```

(The word `master` might be greyed-out, if I could do that.)

Whenever a Git repository is in this state, with `HEAD` attached to a branch name that *doesn't exist*, the *next* commit you make will be a *root commit* (or an "initial" commit as your reflog shows).  So if we now add some files and `git add` and `git commit`, we get the very first commit, which we can call `A`:

```
A   <-- master (HEAD)
```

The new commit has *no parent*, making it a root commit.  The name `master` now springs into being as a real branch name, and `HEAD` remains attached to it.  We're now out of that crazy setup.

We can now make new commits and they'll string along in chains, as we would expect:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
```

We can, however, put Git back into this weird situation, *even though there are commits*, by attaching `HEAD` to a new nonexistent branch name.  We use `git checkout --orphan` to do this (since Git 1.7.2), or `git switch --orphan` (since Git 2.23).  These two are subtly different, so be careful, but you would almost never *want* to use either one, so we won't cover the difference; we'll just illustrate the effect if we were to do one of those with the name `disconnected` and then create some more commits:

```
A--B--C   <-- master

D--E   <-- disconnected (HEAD)
```

That is, the latest commit on `disconnected` is now commit `E`, whose parent is `D`, but commit `D` is a root commit: the going-backwards action stops here.  If we now `git checkout master` or `git switch master`, Git will remove all the commit-`E` files and extract all the commit-`C` files, and `git log` will start at commit `C` and work backwards to `B` and then `A` and then stop.

#### The history in a commit repository is the commits in the repository

History, in Git, is nothing but the commits.  We find the commits from branch or other (e.g., remote-tracking) names, which find a *last* commit, and from there, we have Git work backwards.  Using `git log --graph`, Git will draw the connections from each child commit to its parent(s).

By using trickery like `--orphan`, we can create multiple separate *disconnected* graphs.  They're not very useful, but the theory behind Git allows them, and Git allows them.  It kind of has to, because there's another way to create them, and that's what you stumbled into.

#### What you did

If we:

- create a new, empty repository with `git init`, so that we're on `master` (or even `main`);
- use `git remote add` and `git fetch` to populate the repository with commits and remote-tracking names;
- create and add some files and commit; and
- use the `--guess` mode to create a `develop` branch pointing to their `develop` which our `origin/develop` ...

then we will get a single-commit `master` branch with one root commit on it, plus our own `develop` matching their `origin/develop`.  We'll see, in our work area, their `develop` files; our `master`-branch-single-commit files will not be visible anywhere.

We will have something like this:

```
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- origin/main

K   <-- master
```

depending on whether they have a `main` or a `master` (here I've called it `main` so that we have `origin/main`).

Commit `K` is kind of useless, but it *does* have a bunch of files we might like to be able to see.

#### How to recover

We *could* try to run:

```
git cherry-pick master
```

right now, to add those files to the files we have in our working tree, but this is likely to produce a lot of add/add conflicts.  The reason is that `git cherry-pick` tries to take the *changes* from "their" commit (our `K` in the drawing above), and those "changes" are "add all the files that exist in `K` from scratch".<sup>3</sup>  Git tries to combine them with our "changes", which at this point will be "add all the files in `J`" from scratch.  The result tends to be one giant, massive add/add conflict: not useful.

More useful, probably, is to extract all the files *from* commit `K` into ordinary everyday files, which you can then open in your editor.  To do this, you have a lot of options; the two easiest are:

- `git archive master` will produce a tar or zip archive of all the files in commit `K`, which you can extract in any way you like; or
- `git worktree add ../master` will add a new *working tree* in which the files from branch `master` are checked out in a new directory `../master` (you should be at the top of your working tree when you run this).

The `git worktree add` method creates this working tree and fills it in, so the files are all there for you to see, and you can even do work in there and commit (to add on to your `master`) if that's easier than working here in the `develop` branch.

Once the files are really ready in `../master/*`, you can copy them here and run `git diff` and/or `git add` as desired, and then `git commit` to make a new commit that adds on to commit `J`:

```
               L   <-- develop (HEAD)
              /
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- origin/main

K   <-- master
```

When you're totally satisfied with commit `L` and have successfully used `git push origin develop` to send it to the Git repository over at `origin`, you can delete the added working tree (see `git worktree remove`) and then *delete* your `master` branch, which you don't need any more now that you don't need commit `K`.

Note: commit `K` will remain in your own repository for some time (at least up to a month by default), in case you change your mind and want it back.  To *get* it back you must find its hash ID somehow (e.g., via `git reflog`), and then create a branch or tag name to remember that commit hash ID.  But if you don't ever want it back, after enough time expires, Git will notice that you not only can't see it *normally*, you've never gone back to *find* it, and will throw it out for real.  (This assumes you never `git push` it somewhere else: if you do that, it's much harder to get rid of forever.  Commits are like viruses: once they've infected a couple of repositories, you can't stamp them out easily.)

---

<sup>3</sup>The trick here is that Git is comparing commit `K` to its non-existent parent.  To do that, Git pretends there's a completely-empty commit, using Git's [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) to fake it; that makes all files "newly added".